# Shortcode argument multiple values

Tags: shortcode

Example:
[events_list category=”1,2”]
[/events_list]
returns events in categories 1 or 2.

Is it possible to return events that are in categories both 1 AND 2?  Or does that depend on the plugin?

Thanks.

Comment: you'd need to ask the authors of the `event_list` shortcode, WP doesn't have a concept of multiple parameters in a single attribute, it's just a string `"1,2"`, the comma separated part is purely convention and up to the shortcode's PHP to separate out. You should ask the plugin/theme authors support routes, or in one of their slack/groups/mailing lists/etc as 3rd party plugin/theme dev support is offtopic here

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the plugin. WordPress does not natively support passing multiple values to a shortcode attribute. The value you're passing to the shortcode is simply `'1,2'`. How that value is handled depends entirely on how the shortcode was implemented by the developer.